Let $A:=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}): \hat{f}, \hat{f'} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\}$. Schwartz space is dense in $A$ wrt $\|f\|:= \|\hat{f}\|_1+\|\hat{f'}\|_1$?
Let $A:=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}): \hat{f}, \hat{f'} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\}$, where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Then is it true that Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $A$ w.r.t. $\lVert f\rVert:= \lVert\hat{f}\rVert_1+\lVert\hat{f'}\rVert_1$?
I only know that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
So, can you please guide me on this problem?

This is equivalent to ask if the Schwartz space is dense in $L^1(1+|\xi|) d\xi$ and it is true. Take a functions, approximate first with one with compact support and then use convolution: when the support is fixed you do not see the weight.

It is unclear why my question is equivalent to the Schwartz space being dense in $L^1(1+|ξ|)dξ$. Can you please give a bit of details?

Your have $|f|=|\hat f|_1+|\xi \hat f|_1=|(1+|\xi|)\hat f|_1$. If you approximate $\hat f$ in the weighted $L^1$ norm above, by Schwartz functions $g_n$, then take $f_n$  the inverse transforms of $g_n$.

The definition of $A$ is not very clear. If $f$ is not of temperate growth I don't know how to define $\hat{f}$.

We implicitly assume all necessary conditions that are required to exist $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{f'}$.
